# Apollo: How to Sort Subscription Results in UpdateQuery?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollostack

Here is a working Apollo subscription handler:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const fromID = Meteor.userId();
    const {toID} = this.props;
    this.toID = toID;

    this.props.data.subscribeToMore({
        document: IM_SUBSCRIPTION_QUERY,
        variables: {
            fromID: fromID,
            toID: toID,
        },
        updateQuery: (prev, {subscriptionData}) => {
            if (!subscriptionData.data) {
                return prev;
            }
            const newIM = subscriptionData.data.IMAdded;
            // don't double add the message
            if (isDuplicateIM(newIM, prev.instant_message)) {
                return previousResult;
            }
            return update(prev, {
                instant_message: {
                    $push: [newIM],
                },
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`instant_message` is an array of objects to be displayed. Each object contains a date field. I need to sort the objects in this array by date.

This approach used to work with beta versions of Apollo:

```
//update returns a new "immutable" list
const instant_message = update(previousResult, {instant_message: {$push: [newAppt]}});
instant_message.instant_message = instant_message.instant_message.sort(sortIMsByDateHelper);
return instant_message;
```

I can sort the array, but Apollo throws an error with the returned object-- e.g. it is not found in props when the `render` routine needs it.

What is the correct way to return the sorted array from `updateQuery`? Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it wasn't the sorting that was causing the anomaly.  It appears that subscriptions fail if the `__TYPENAME` of the returned object doesn't match something else here -- either the varname used in this routine ('instant_message' in the above code), or the varname of the array of objects returned in `props` to the render function. Lining up all these things so that they are identical fixes it.